# objective-c index in an Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

i need u help. Problem: have an array in which the object 4, and I have a button when you press play a sound and change (+1) the index of the array => when the user clicks the second time, the sound should be played with the index "2" etc. The problem is that the index does not change, and play files with index "1".

***.h:**

```
@interface AZViewController : UIViewController

{

    NSInteger _acatindex;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *acat;

- (IBAction)catbutt:(id)sender;
```

***.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //array

    NSMutableArray *acat = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"cat1", @"cat2", @"cat3", @"cat4", nil];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[acat objectAtIndex:_acatindex] withExtension:@"wav"];
    NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid.");
    NSError* error = nil;
    self.catplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if(!self.catplayer)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
    }

}
    //button action
- (IBAction)catbutt:(id)sender
{    
    _acatindex++;
    if (_acatindex == _acat.count)
    {
        _acatindex = 0;
    }

    AZTrace();
    [self.catplayer stop];
    [self stopTimer];
    self.catplayer.currentTime = 0;
    [self.catplayer prepareToPlay];

    AZTrace();
    [self.catplayer play];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines:

```
    [acat addObject:@"cat1"];
    [acat addObject:@"cat2"];
    [acat addObject:@"cat3"];
    [acat addObject:@"cat4"];
```

Declare your array and NSURL not in viewDidLoad, Do this instead in your .h:

```
@interface AZViewController : UIViewController

{

    NSInteger _acatindex;
     NSMutableArray *acat;
    NSURL *url;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *acat;

- (IBAction)catbutt:(id)sender;
```

Now cut the following code from `viewDidLoad()`:

```
url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[acat objectAtIndex:_acatindex] withExtension:@"wav"];
    NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid.");
    NSError* error = nil;

self.catplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if(!self.catplayer)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
    }
```

and paste it in `- (IBAction)catbutt:(id)sender` above `_acatindex++;`

Hope this will help.

Comment: @VELDT  You are welcome. But please do sum search before you post, if you wanna survive in this site.

Answer (score 0):

You only load the URL in the `-viewDidLoad:` method. You need to tell the audio player to play the next sound in the array in the `-catbutt:` method. You're stopping the player, but you aren't changing the file that it's playing before restarting it.

Comment: please explain to me in detail, if that is possible on an example